# Can't use Perl syntax to test html web page with Selenium?

Tags: html, css, perl, selenium, testing

I want to create a test to check a form using perl. And i have to catch an id from html/css. In Selenium. How i can do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and the Perl tag. While it's nice how colorful your code is, [a screenshot is not very helpful](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/1331451), because we cannot copy code from it. How are we supposed to run your code to try to help you solve issues? Speaking of issues, what exactly is your problem? We would need to see the HTML or the DOM structure of the page you are trying to interact with here. From the error messages, it looks like your code has a syntax error in line 16, but I don't know which line that is. Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In `my @login => 'fahd'`, @login is an empty array, so only `'fahd'` is returned. Therefore, you're calling

```
$s->submit_form_ok({ input => { 'fahd' => undef }, # plus the "odd number" warning
                     click => '@submit',
                   });
```

(`fahd` was removed from the source, but is still readable in the output.)

Comment: @ikegami: You're right. That's because I can't copy the source from the screenshot and have to constantly scroll up and down between it and the edit area :-(

Answer (score 1):

```
input => { my @login => 'fahd' }
```

is the same thing as

```
input => { 'fahd' }
```

since the newly-created array by `@login` is empty.

The hash initializing expression is expected to return key-value pairs, but only a single value is returned. That's why you're getting the error message "odd number of elements in anonymous hash".

And since the keys of the hash are expected to be locators, that's why you get the error message "Element fahd not found".

I suspect you meant to use

```
$s->submit_form_ok({
   input => { '@login' => 'fahd' },
   click => '@submit',
})
```

But that brings up a second problem. I don't think `@login` and `@submit` are valid Selenium locators, which is why you are getting "Element @submit not found". Selenium accepts multiple styles of selectors, one of which being CSS selectors. In CSS selectors, `#id` finds nodes by id.

```
$s->submit_form_ok({
   input => { '#login' => 'fahd' },
   click => '#submit',
})
```

Comment: Neither 2 methods work

Comment: My main goal was to address the problem that was holding you up (the bad hash construction). I don't know much about Selenium, and you provided no information about the structure of the form/page, so the rest is all guess work.

Comment: i understand. Thanks again for support